# trouble with hg serve on the lan

Tags: mercurial

Our team started using mercurial about a month ago and it was a rough start, but it's working out well now. At the end of last week though, we suddenly had issues pulling from each other's repositories.

Normally, I would pull from, for example, prog12:800, and it would work great. Now, I get the message
URLError: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

The hg server is running, and it's not a firewall issue. This issue only occurs when trying to access my repo and two other people's. Accessing everyone else's, and the one on our webdev server, is fine. We are all on the same lan (though two of us connect via vpn) We all have the same issue - from my own computer, i can type in my computer name:8000 and it works, but no one else can see it.

I appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It it possible your IT department deployed something that's acting as a firewall on each machine?  Being able to connect to your own port 8000, but not others' just screams firewalls.

That said, most people don't actually run `hg serve` on developer boxes.  Instead you let each developer freely create repos on the "central" "webdev" box.  So I might create 'work-in-progress-ry4an' and do push/pull from there, and other can pull from it.

The `hg serve` functionality is a great way to pass someone some quick changesets, but not built to be used as an always-on server.

Comment: I work from home so no one installed anything on my machine... As for running hg serve - thanks for the suggestion, we are new to mercurial and had to figure it out ourselves. What you suggest about all the repos on the central server makes a lot of sense. How does everyone connect to the server though? ssh? we are all running windows (except the server, linux) Thanks!

Comment: @estherh: what you ask is covered in [the wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) and has been asked many times here and on the [mailinglist](http://mercurial.markmail.org/search/?q=central+server+windows+list%3Acom.selenic.mercurial).

Comment: @MartinGeisler thanks for the links. we are still having trouble pulling with hg server and no idea what it could be. but since our central server is already overloaded, we are thinking of going to hosted solutions, as you saw here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969825/how-does-code-hosting-work-with-a-staging-environment/8970014#8970014

Comment: I'm confused.  Your questions says on the LAN, but now you say you work from home.

Aside: make sure you're bound to IP "0.0.0.0" not "127.0.0.1"

Comment: @Ry4an - sorry for the delay, I just noticed your comment now. I work from home and connect to the company's lan with vpn. does that make sense? I don't understand what you mean about binding the IP to 0.0.0.0..... I am accepting your answer because (1) it's the only answer! and (2) i appreciate your advice about e/o having their own repos on the central server, which is what we will be setting up now. As a side note - we are suddenly able to access each other's repos now with hg serve, but I have no idea what changed again.

Comment: I appreciate it, but if you want to keep working on getting this going   feel free to re-open the question.